# recursive data subset based on column attributes in R

Tags: r, loops, recursion

I have a data frame with 10K rows and 6 columns. The first two columns are factors.

```
 A     B     C     D      E       F
 A1    B1   0.1   0.2    0.3      0.4
 A2    B2   .........................
 A1    B3   .........................
 A1    B1   0.3   ...................
```

Now I want to generate models(using my function F) based on different subsets of data (different rows), that is different combinations of attributes of A and B.

In my above example,  I should have call my function F 6 times with Cartesian production of A and B
(A1,A2) x (B1,B2,B3).  I wonder how to do this in R efficiently without explicit loop?

To avoid confusion
e.g, apply F to (A1,B1) combination, in this case, rows 1 and 4, columns 3 to 6.
to other combinations is similar

Comment: I assume that you are only interested in the first two columns of your dataframe to call your function. Is that right?

Comment: No, I need to select rows based on different combination of A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
lapply(seq_len(length(df$A)*length(df$B))-1, function(x)
  myFunction(df[df$A == paste0("A",1+floor(x / length(df$B))) &
                df$B == paste0("B",1+(x %% length(df$B))), ]))
```

Comment: could you explain a little bit here? How should apply F to each subset?

Comment: The statements within the brackets select A and B matching `c(A1,B1)`, `c(A1,B2)`, etc.